# mysqli_connect большое время коннекта

Tags: mysqli, php

```
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
    $time_stop = microtime(true);
    die($time_stop-$time_start);
```

возращает 1.0171918869019
Это очень много что делать?

Comment: может ваш mysql сервер находиться на другом конце света при этом подключен через модем 14400. Тогда это ещё очень быстро.

А может сервер загружен select'ами по пару мегабайт десятками в секунду.

Comment: БД находиться на локальном компьютере и скрипт тоже на нем выполняется, нагрузка на сервер нулевая

Comment: тогда нужно решить, кто винован - php или база. Подключитесь к базе ручками (например через консоль или какой-нибудь утилитой - они часто показывают, сколько времени потратилось). Запустите свой скрипт с консоли (php filename.php).

Может у Вас фаервол?

Comment: посаветуйте утилиту

Comment: а чем стандартный mysql клиент плох? (консольный который)

Comment: через консоль все нормально

Comment: `mysql -uuser_name -ppassword`, по крайней мере в linux именно так.
Кроме того http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

есть родная графическая утилита

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что проблема в dns. Попробуйте подключиться по адресу 127.0.0.1 вместо localhost и почитать это.

Comment: Респект тебе, сам бы не за что не догадался.
Теперь показывает 0.0019030570983887

Comment: можно еще прописать в hosts файл правильно. Это даже лучше в многих случаях. Под линуском оно уже так обычно. Под виндой - не всегда. Где искать этот файл - написано [wiki](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts). Прописывать нужно вида

    127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: да помогает

Comment: как я понял это связанос IPv6?

Comment: вот этого я не знаю. Я знаю только что dns клиент пытается резолвить "localhost", может он вначале получает ipv6 адрес, по которому никто и не слушает.